# Сортировка слов в массиве

Tags: java

у меня есть массив слов полученный из строки, как мне отсортировать слова в этом массиве по количеству гласных в нем?

```java
public class MyLine {
    private final String line;

    public MyLine(String line) {
        this.line = line;
    }
    public void vowelsCount(){
        if(line == null){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("the word cannot be null!");
        }
        Pattern vowels = Pattern.compile("(?iu)[ауоыиэяюёе]");

        Matcher matcher = vowels.matcher(line);
        int vowelsCounter = 0;
        while (matcher.find()) {
            vowelsCounter++;
        }
        System.out.println("Результат: " + vowelsCounter + " гласных");
    }

    public void sortWords(){
        Pattern vowels = Pattern.compile("(?iu)[ауоыиэяюёе]");
        String[] words = line.split("\\s+");
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            Matcher matcher = vowels.matcher(words[i]);
            int vowelsCounter = 0;
            while (matcher.find()) {
                vowelsCounter++;
            }
            System.out.println("в слове: " + "'" + words[i] + "'" + " " + vowelsCounter + " гласная(гласных)");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyLine example = new MyLine("ввод гласных букв");
        example.vowelsCount();
        example.sortWords();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Введите отдельный класс для слова. Что-то вроде

```
class Word implements Comparable<Word> {
        private String content;
        public Word(String str) {
            content = str;
        }
        public int getVowelsCount() {
            //тут подсчет гласных в слове
            return 25;
        }
        public String getContent() {
            return content;
        }
        @Override
        public int compareTo(Word o) {
            return getVowelsCount() - o.getVowelsCount();
        }
    }
```

2. Класс MyLine переработатйте во что-то вроде

```
    class MyLine {
        private final String line;
        public MyLine(String line) {
            this.line = line;
        }
        public List<String> sortWords(){
            return Arrays.stream(line.split("\\s+"))
                    .map(str -> new Word(str))
                    .sorted()
                    .map(Word::getContent)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
        public void printSortedList() {
            System.out.println(sortWords());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
    private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[aeiouy]");

    public static void main(String args[]) throws SocketException {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("tree", "dog", "population", "revision", "fire");
        list.sort(Comparator.comparing((i -> getValue(i))));
    }

    private static Integer getValue(String string) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
        int i = 0;
        while (matcher.find()) {
            i++;
        }
        return i;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Имеет смысл сохранить массив слов как поле класса `MyLine` с соответствующим геттером, отсортировать его в методе `sortByVowelCount`.

Для подсчёта гласных можно использовать метод `Stream::count` для потока `Stream<MatchResult>`, который возвращается из метода [`Matcher::results`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results--) в Java 9:

```java
class MyLine {
    private final String line;
    private String[] words;
    
    private static final Pattern VOWELS = Pattern.compile("(?iu)[aeiouаяеэёоиыую]");
    
    public MyLine(String line) {
        this.line = line;
        this.words = line.split("\\s+");
    }
    
    public void sortByVowelCount() {
        Arrays.sort(this.words, Comparator.comparingLong(
            s -> VOWELS.matcher(s).results().count()
        ));
    }
    
    public String[] getWords() {
        return this.words;
    }
}
```

Тест:

```java
MyLine line = new MyLine("Здравствуйте я тётушка Чарли из Бразилии");
line.sortByVowelCount();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(line.getWords()));
// -> [я, из, Чарли, Здравствуйте, тётушка, Бразилии]
```